# MSM files for the Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 not found?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have been using visual studio 2010 for long time now and just upgraded to VS 2015 (installed with default options). But I'm not able to find MSMs such as `Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm`

Where are the MSM files for the 2015 VC runtime?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VC++ 2015 MSMs are located in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Merge Modules`.

From [Redistributing Visual C++ Files / Locate the redistributable files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=msvc-160#locate-the-redistributable-files):

> Another deployment option is to use redistributable merge modules (.msm files). In Visual Studio 2019, these files are part of an optional installable component named C++ 2019 Redistributable MSMs in the Visual Studio Installer. The merge modules are installed by default as part of a C++ install in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2015. When installed in the latest version of Visual Studio 2019, you'll find the redistributable merge modules in `%VCINSTALLDIR%Redist\MSVC\v142\MergeModules`. In both Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2017, they're also found in `%VCToolsRedistDir%MergeModules`. In Visual Studio 2015, they're found in `Program Files [(x86)]\Common Files\Merge Modules`.

It is important that the VC++ runtimes be installed with proper version checking, since the major version and file names have stayed the same between VC++ 2015, 2017 and 2019.

From [C++ binary compatibility between Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160#upgrade-the-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-from-visual-studio-2015-or-2017-to-visual-studio-2019):

> We've kept the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable major version number the same for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019. That means only one instance of the Redistributable can be installed at a time.

Comment: VC++ runtime wasn't installed with default option

Comment: @Austin It's been a long time, but I thought VS 2015 installed the redistributables by default when C++ was selected (and the docs seem to imply that, too). It is an optional package that needs to be specifically selected in VS 2019 though.

Comment: For me default didn't work and in custom I selected all and installed, worked smoothly.